# Ext JS Border layout: how to collapse a region programmatically?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a panel with "border" layout, having "center" and "north" region.
I want to programmatically collapse the north region, and according to the forum the way to do that is:

```
container.layout.north.collapse();
```

However, container.layout is a string object thus container.layout.north giving me null object.

Does anyone have a 2 seconds pointer on how to get a handle to the correct layout object to call collapse() upon?

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest way would be to get hold of the panel you need by calling `Ext.getCmp()`. For you the `container.layout` is undefined because it not an object of Ext.Component. Set an Id for you border panel or any panel you need access to.

```
 var panel = Ext.getCmp('BorderPanelId');
 panel.layout.north.collapse();
```

Another way would be to use the north panel's Id. In that case you will:

```
 var panel = Ext.getCmp('NorthPanelId');
 panel.collapse();
```

Another way would be to make user of the `ref` system. Set the ref property for your panels. And if you have access to component's owner.. you can simple use the ref to reference the panel or other components.

Comment: panel.layout is not null. it contains an object of type string. it's as if the layout object is not yet constructed. i'm 97.43% sure that this have something to do with the fact that i'm trying to collapse() a panel that is not yet shown (it's in the bottom part of a 'card' layout stack).

Answer (score 1):

In Extjs 4 you can do:

```
panel.getLayout().regions.north.collapse();
```

Then to reactivate the region:

```
panel.getLayout().regions.north.expand();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Ext JS 4 you can do:

```
container.down('[region=north]').collapse();
```

That's the easiest and recommended way.